# Get current "Power Apps per App Plan" - License Usage

Tags: office365, dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

i can assign 'power apps per app plan'-licenses to a specific app. I can see how many licenses i have assigned. But i am unable to find an overview of the current usage of the license.
I want to see the users who are using an license right now and who had used a license in the past..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- https://admin.powerplatform.com

  - Specifically `Analytics/PowerApps` or `Resources/Capacity` OR
- https://admin.microsoft.com under `Billing/Licenses`

Comment: thanks, but thats where i can only see the current usage in total, like 10 out of 20 are assigned..but i want to know who (the specific user) is using one of these 10 licenses right know (or, if thats not possible, the usage in the past)